# Creating multiple users in Bluemix Biginsight to test Knox service

Tags: ibm-cloud, knox-gateway

I have created a space and a BigInsight cluster on Bluemix. In order to test Knox, I need multiple users for authentication. Is it possible to create users in Bluemix Biginsight service? The ID that is provided to access the cluster does not have root access. Also, it would be helpful if someone can explain in detail how the admin-related task(adding more components like Hue,Drill using yum commands) could be performed in Bluemix Biginsights service. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid getting some push-back from the Stack Overflow community, please state what you have already tried. Stack Overflow is really for problem and solution questions and not for answering whether it is possible to do something. This type of question would be more appropriate for dW Answers: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here that you have created a Bluemix Biginsights Basic (Beta) plan.
This service is a single user service and cannot have multiple users.
In addition this service is a managed service and installation of software by the user is not allowed.
This service comes with preconfigured settings and pre-installed softwares that is fixed. If you do need something apart from this, I would suggest to open a Biginsights service ticket through Bluemix Support page with a request for it and why you need the software.

The product management team will look at it and see if they can be preinstalled in the future release.

These installations will not be done on a any Basic (Beta) plan for individual clusters.